# setting up nfs for crunchy-postgresql-cluster on CoreOS

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, coreos

I am looking at installing crunchy-postgresql-cluster on CoreOS Kubernetes.  I didn't have nfs setup in my cloud-config when I built my server.

I looked at crunchy-postgresql-cluster file link [crunchy-pgsql-values.yaml](https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-containers/blob/master/examples/kubehelm/crunchy-postgresql-cluster/values.yaml)

And see that they are using nfs:

```
#NFSServerIP: 192.168.122.210
NFSServerIP: 10.138.154.1
NFSPath: /nfsfileshare
```

I swapped in one of my nodes private ip but I see the following error when I do a describe on my pod:

```
timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"banking-seagull-crunchy-master". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[pgdata]
```

I looked at [link](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/storage/nfs/) but still not sure how to get nfs working.

Comment: Take a look at the kubelet logs. That might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this helps others:

I set up a NFS server on one of my nodes.

create or update /etc/exports entry to add a file dir to share

```
/nfsfileshare <PRIVATE_IP>(rw,async)
```

Executed the following

```
sudo systemctl start rpc-mountd
sudo systemctl enable rpc-mountd

sudo systemctl start nfsd 
sudo systemctl enable nfsd
```

and it worked.